# Table name is invalid until I use the fully qualified name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
select *
from PLAYERS
```

Gives me an error:

> Invalid object name 'players'.

But, this works:

```
select *
from tennis.dbo.PLAYERS
```

Why? I keep on using only the table name in many other examples without problems.
Then why do I get errors only here?

Comment: You are either not connected to the `Tennis` database, in which case put `USE Tennis` at the start of your query, or `dbo` is not you default schema, meaning you have to schema qualify your table.

Comment: Please read this post about always using the schema prefix when creating or referencing objects: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create [synonyms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) for the tables so you don't have to use the four part name.